# Pathspec upstream/master is ambiguous

Tags: git, github

I can push, pull and checkout upstream/master no problem at all but I do get a warning.
Upstream/master is for tracking the changes made to the original source code from which I forked (having followed github instructions).

E.g.

```
$ git checkout upstream/master
warning: refname upstream/master is ambiguous

$ git branch -a
* master
  upstream/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/master
```

This command also has the ambiguous error:

```
$ git branch
* master
  upstream/master

$ git checkout upstream/master filename.bar
```

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.mono-project.com/GitFAQ#I_get_an_ambiguous_warning_when_checking_out_a_branch) mentions the usual cause for this kind of message:

> When you try to checkout a local branch, you get a

```
warning: refname 'branch-name' is ambiguous
```

> This can happen **if you've created a local branch with the same name as a remote tag**.
>   Git should be checking out your local branch, but instead it's trying to checkout the tag, and it gets confused.
>
> In general, when creating tags, be careful not to have names that conflict with existing (local or remote) branches.